# How do I model the cooling coil based on specific parameters to find efficiency of heat flow (input) to air/water?

Tags: openmodelica

I am undergraduate student and have just started learning how to model HVAC systems using the open modelica connection editor. I have learnt through the building library examples and came across the tutorial on space cooling. I tried editing the existing model to apply my own parameters to try and find the efficiency of the heat transfer between the air and water mediums.

The code is extract based on the example from :https://simulationresearch.lbl.gov/modelica/releases/v9.0.0/help/Buildings_Examples_Tutorial_SpaceCooling.html#Buildings.Examples.Tutorial.SpaceCooling.System3

My edited code is as follows:

```
model AHU2

  replaceable package MediumA = Buildings.Media.Air "Medium for air";
  replaceable package MediumW = Buildings.Media.Water "Medium for water";
  
   parameter Modelica.Units.SI.Volume V=1022*3
  //Room volume
  ;

//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
  // Heat recovery effectiveness
  parameter Real eps = 0.8 "Heat recovery effectiveness";

/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
  // Design air conditions
  parameter Modelica.Units.SI.Temperature TASup_nominal=285.15
    "Nominal air temperature supplied to room";
  parameter Modelica.Units.SI.DimensionlessRatio wASup_nominal=0.012
    "Nominal air humidity ratio supplied to room [kg/kg] assuming 90% relative humidity";
  parameter Modelica.Units.SI.Temperature TRooSet=297.15
    "Nominal room air temperature";
  parameter Modelica.Units.SI.Temperature TOut_nominal=309.15
    "Design outlet air temperature";
  parameter Modelica.Units.SI.Temperature THeaRecLvg=TOut_nominal - eps*(
      TOut_nominal - TRooSet) "Air temperature leaving the heat recovery";
  parameter Modelica.Units.SI.DimensionlessRatio wHeaRecLvg=0.0135
    "Air humidity ratio leaving the heat recovery [kg/kg]";

/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
  // Cooling loads and air mass flow rates
  parameter Modelica.Units.SI.HeatFlowRate QRooInt_flow=12881
    "Internal heat gains of the room (10msq/person at 70W/m2*1.8m2 per person)";
  parameter Modelica.Units.SI.HeatFlowRate QRooC_flow_nominal=-QRooInt_flow -
      10E3/30*(TOut_nominal - TRooSet) "Nominal cooling load of the room";
  parameter Modelica.Units.SI.MassFlowRate mA_flow_nominal=3.3
    "Nominal air mass flow rate, based on 17M AHU rated specification";
  parameter Modelica.Units.SI.TemperatureDifference dTFan=2
    "Estimated temperature raise across fan that needs to be made up by the cooling coil";
  parameter Modelica.Units.SI.HeatFlowRate QCoiC_flow_nominal=mA_flow_nominal*(
      TASup_nominal - THeaRecLvg - dTFan)*1006 + mA_flow_nominal*(wASup_nominal
       - wHeaRecLvg)*2458.3e3
    "Cooling load of coil, taking into account outside air sensible and latent heat removal";

/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
  // Water temperatures and mass flow rates
  parameter Modelica.Units.SI.Temperature TWSup_nominal=280.35
    "Water supply temperature";
  parameter Modelica.Units.SI.Temperature TWRet_nominal=285.955
    "Water return temperature";
  parameter Modelica.Units.SI.MassFlowRate mW_flow_nominal=2.5
   "Nominal water mass flow rate";
```

After simulating of the model, I still get Q1_flow = Q2_flow despite trying to vary the mass flow rates of air and water to vary Q1 and Q2. I wanted the values of Q1 and Q2 to be different so that I could get the ratio to find efficiency of the cooling coil component. I suspect that the heat exchanger component of the model (Buildings.Fluid.HeatExchangers.WetCoilEffectivenessNTU) uses the Q nominal value set in the cooling coil component which ignores the calculation of the the Q flow from water and instead takes the Q flow of air.

[Simulation results of the model](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KHn4q.png)

The code for the cooling coil component:

```
Buildings.Fluid.HeatExchangers.WetCoilEffectivenessNTU cooCoi(redeclare package Medium1 = MediumW, redeclare package Medium2 = MediumA, **Q_flow_nominal = QCoiC_flow_nominal**,T_a1_nominal = TWSup_nominal, T_a2_nominal = THeaRecLvg, dp1_nominal = 6000, dp2_nominal = 200, energyDynamics = Modelica.Fluid.Types.Dynamics.FixedInitial, m1_flow_nominal = mW_flow_nominal, m2_flow_nominal = mA_flow_nominal, show_T = true, use_Q_flow_nominal = true, w_a2_nominal = wHeaRecLvg) annotation(
```

[Diagram View of model](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nvsyy.png)

Am I missing any key parameters or is the example model itself not suitable for my application? Are the parameters I set correct for the simulation or should I use other cooling coil components to model the efficiency? Any advise on how to model a AHU to find efficiency of heat flow between air and water in the cooling coil by varying the flow rates?

Any help is appreciate, thanks!